# I need to build Chromium after I include some dependencies

Tags: linker, chromium, ninja, gn

I am simply building Chromium windows. It builds perfectly and works in every configuration I try. When I modify the source code, to include, in select_file_picker_win.cpp

```
#include "chrome/browser/ui/browser.h"
#include "chrome/browser/ui/browser_window.h"
#include "content/public/browser/navigation_controller.h"
```

doesn't work.

The problem is that it can't link to the object generated.
Unresolved symbol browser.create

I tried different linkers, different compilers, different gn gen configurations, and same.

**Where do I need to tell gn or ninja about this, to add this object when linking this file?**

Something changes when i modify the ninja file inside the out folder, related to selectfile.. the error becomes a *cyclic redundancy* problem, and the file gets overwritten anyway so i know it is not the right solution.

> lld-link: ←[0;31merror: ←[0mundefined symbol: public: __cdecl
> Browser::CreateParams::CreateParams(enum Browser::Type, class Profile
> *, bool)

Edit:

I modified BUILD.gn to add this:

```
deps = [
        "//base",
        "//base:i18n",
        "//build:chromeos_buildflags",
        "//skia",
        "//ui/base",
        "//ui/strings",
        "//url",
        "//chrome/browser",
        
      ]

allow_circular_includes_from = [
    "//chrome/browser",
]
```

but the BUILD.gn from chrome/browser includes the previous, so I expected a cyclic redundancy. I have it:

> ERROR Dependency cycle:   //content:content ->
> //content/gpu:gpu_sources ->   //content/child:child ->
> //content/common:common ->   //ui/shell_dialogs:shell_dialogs ->
> //chrome/browser:browser ->   //apps:apps ->
> //components/keyed_service/content:content ->
> //content/public/browser:browser ->   //content:content
>
> FAILED: build.ninja

so I added this:

```
allow_circular_includes_from = [
    "//chrome/browser/devtools",
    "//chrome/browser/profiling_host",
    "//chrome/browser/ui",
    "//chrome/browser/ui/webui/bluetooth_internals",
    "//chrome/browser/storage_access_api:permissions",
    "//chrome/browser/safe_browsing",
    "//chrome/browser/safe_browsing:verdict_cache_manager_factory",
    "//chrome/browser/safe_browsing:advanced_protection",
    "//chrome/browser/safe_browsing:metrics_collector",
    "//ui/shell_dialogs",
```

> ```
> [0/1] Regenerating ninja files
> ERROR Dependency cycle:
>   //content:content ->
>   //content/gpu:gpu_sources ->
>   //content/child:child ->
>   //content/common:common ->
>   //ui/shell_dialogs:shell_dialogs ->
>   //chrome/browser:browser ->
>   //apps:apps ->
>   //components/keyed_service/content:content ->
>   //content/public/browser:browser ->
>   //content:content
>
> FAILED: build.ninja
> ../../buildtools/win/gn.exe --root=../.. -q --ide=vs --regeneration gen .
> ninja: error: rebuilding 'build.ninja': subcommand failed
> ```

Edit:
https://github.com/skopf/minimal-gn-project
this does not work, complains about gn.exe missing, but gn is both in the path and current dir,

When component build = false,

> //content/browser:browser ->   //content/common:common ->
> //ui/shell_dialogs:shell_dialogs ->   //chrome/browser:browser ->
> //apps:apps ->   //components/keyed_service/content:content ->
> //content/public/browser:browser ->
> //content/public/browser:browser_sources ->
> //content/browser:browser

the dependencies are different, same error.
I tried adding

```
allow_circular_includes_from = [
  "//ui/shell_dialogs",
  "//content/common",
  ]
```

but does not solve anything, in any of the files.

C:\q\src>gn gen out/q

> ERROR Dependency cycle:   //content/browser:browser ->
> //content/common:common ->   //ui/shell_dialogs:shell_dialogs ->
> //chrome/browser:browser ->   //apps:apps ->
> //components/keyed_service/content:content ->
> //content/public/browser:browser ->
> //content/public/browser:browser_sources ->
> //content/browser:browser

Comment: You have to modify a specific `BUILD.gn` file to add the necessary source files or libraries. Look up how to use `GN` build system: https://gn.googlesource.com/gn/

Comment: Thank you very much! I will keep this thread updated

Comment: You need to learn the GN build system properly. Spend some time with it. Just including cpp files in source tag should suffice in most of the cases

Comment: Oh. I am reading it thoroughly but i was a bit scared to modify the source tag. I will definitely give it a try. I was designing a solution where there is a new component or group with new sources and they import the other headers and librarie, but I will try your answer first as it seems simpler and i didnt try. Thank you very much!

Comment: It's better to try doing so with a simple skeleton project. Doing so in Chromium might trigger recompilation from scratch again, I have faced that so many times. It will be faster and easier to learn from a skeleton project too

Comment: I did it, and works as I thought it should work. I am trying to replicate the error in this new project but it's easy to fix, unlike the Chromium one. I am not sure why. I will take a closer look or try to add a new source that includes both. Thanks again

Comment: I cnt find a solution yet, I understand the gn system, I have been building more projects, tried all combinations of arguments... There must be something i am missing. I don't like gn